# Remove an item from each hash in an Array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
array = [{
  "id"=>"ABC",
  "account"=>"XYZ", 
  "date"=>"2014-07-21",
  "amount"=>200,  
  "score"=>{"location"=>{"city"=>1, "state"=>1}, "name"=>1},
  "cat"=>#<Tipper::Category:0xb666fb0
    @type={"primary"=>"special"},
    @hierarchy=["Transfer","Withdrawal", "ATM"],
    @id="21012002"
  >,  
  "state"=>"CA"
},
{"id=>"XYZ","account"=>"987"}]
```

I want to iterate through each hash in the array and remove the "category" piece from each hash and produce an array of hashes without the "category" item in any of the hashes. I tried this:

```
filtered_array = array.reject { |t| array.include? t['cat'] }
```

This is not doing it.

Comment: Whatever you have is invalid.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The data is called `array`, but the code snippet never references `array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map and delete

this will work the actual instances of the hashes, so the array will be modified.

```
array.each{ |hash| hash.delete('cat') }
```

you can do this to get a new array and keep the first one non touched.

```
new_array = array.map do |hash| 
   new_hash = hash.dup
   new_hash.delete('cat')
   new_hash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of hashes:

```
array = [ {"id" => 1, "name" => "bob", "cat" => "dog"}, 
          {"id" => 2, "name" => "jim", "cat" => "mouse"}, 
          {"id" => 1, "name" => "nick", "cat" => "fish"} ]
```

You can do something like the following:

```
array.map { |hash| hash.reject {|k, v| k == "cat" } }
```

This returns a new array of hashes with the `cat` pairs removed, while still preserving the original array:

```
=> [{:id=>1, :name=>"bob"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"jim"}, {:id=>1, :name=>"nick"}]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You have to return the hash in the map block, because `delete` will return the value of the deleted key. So your solution will return an array of the `categories`.

Comment: And you should note that the hashes in the array will all be modified, so the subject array and the resulting array are identical, and contains the same instances. Which is not what I would suggest.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I have actually just modified my code to use `reject`. This returns the desired array of hashes, while still preserving the original array.